# MySQL Trigger inserts null instead of values

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm having trouble understanding how triggers execute in MySQL and I'm banging my head on the wall, because I can't seem to find out why it doesn't work.

I have the following trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER Insert_Products BEFORE INSERT ON `Products`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE x_ProductID INT;
    SET x_ProductID = NEW.`ProductID`;

    SET NEW.`PriceExVAT` = (
        SELECT
            ROUND(p.`Price` * 100 / (100 + v.`VATPercentage`), 2) as priceexvat
        FROM
            `Products` p
        LEFT JOIN
            `VAT` v ON p.`VATID` = v.`VATID`
        WHERE p.`ProductID` = x_ProductID); -- also tried inserting NEW.`ProductID` directly into this line
END $$
```

However it populates my rows with `null` instead of the correct values. HOWEVER, putting it in a select query results the correct values. IE:

```
SELECT
    ROUND(p.`Price` * 100 / (100 + v.`VATPercentage`), 2) as x_value
FROM
    `Products` p
LEFT JOIN
    `VAT` v ON p.`VATID` = v.`VATID`
WHERE p.`ProductID` = 1;
```

I tried putting it in an `AFTER INSERT` trigger, but that resulted in a different error. What am I not seeing, how should I fix this?

Comment: It seems to be a problem related to inserting new values into a table. `\`Products\`.\`ProductID\`` is `INT(11) UNSIGNED NN AI` so the value is not inserted. How would I still use this value in a `BEFORE INSERT ON` trigger?

Comment: From [MySQL 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) : "In a BEFORE trigger, the NEW value for an AUTO_INCREMENT column is 0, not the sequence number that is generated automatically when the new row actually is inserted." So how would I be able to use an AI value in a trigger?

Comment: You do not need to query the table product (and thus you do not need the id). Use new.vatid to (only) query the vat-table, and new.price and so on to calculate the value.

Comment: how would i return a single value from the statement then? The productID is required to return a single value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to query the `product`-table for the values of the currently inserted row: apart from the autoincrement id, they are provided in `NEW`, and you can use them directly:

```
SET NEW.`PriceExVAT` = ( 
    SELECT ROUND(NEW.`Price` * 100 / (100 + v.`VATPercentage`), 2) as priceexvat
    FROM `VAT` v 
    WHERE NEW.`VATID` = v.`VATID`
  )
```

You can do the same in an `before update`-trigger.

Comment: I totally get what you're saying right now yeah! You're right. Thanks for helping me out :)